# How to output multiple file extensions stored in a .txt file on Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, file-extension, scanning

my purpose is to output the files with the extensions that match the ones I store on a .txt file but I don't know how to make it work. The way I am trying to do now does not generate any output or output the files of the extensions that are not on the text file (Extension.txt) I indicate. How am I supposed to fix this? 
The content in my .txt file is:

```
*.xlsx,*.xlsm,*.xlsb,*.xltx,*.xltm,*.xls,*.xml
```

My current code is as followed:

```
$fileHeaders = @('country','cDrive','dDrive')
$extensions  = ${C:temp:Extension.txt}

$LocContent = Import-Csv "C:\temp\Location.txt" -Header $fileHeaders

$NumberOfDays = Read-Host 'Within how many days the files created would you like to output?'
$SizeOfFile = Read-Host 'Above what size of the files would you like to output (in kb or mb)?'

$Output = ForEach($Row in $LocContent){
    if (($Row.country -ne $null) -and ($Row.cDrive -ne $null) -and ($Row.dDrive -ne $null)){
        Get-ChildItem $Row.cDrive,$Row.dDrive -Force -Include -Recurse |
$extensions             Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$NumberOfDays) |
                 Where-Object {$_.length/$SizeOfFile -gt 1} | 
                    Select-Object -Property @{N='File Basename';E={$_.BaseName}}, 
                        @{N='File Extension';E={$_.Extension}},
                        @{N='size in MB';E={$_.Length/1024kb}},
                        Directory,
                        CreationTime, 
                        LastWriteTime, 
                        @{N="Location";E={$Row.country}}         
}

$Output | Format-Table -Auto
$Output | Out-Gridview
$Output | Export-Csv '\NewData.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

This both generated the files, outputs the files and makes sure they are in your .txt file.

I am not surprised your code wont work. You were doing it fairly poorly. Look forward to seeing you improve.

```
$extensions = ((Get-Content C:\temp\Extensions.txt) -join ',') -split ',' -replace '\*',''

Foreach($ext in $extensions){
    Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -Recurse | select Name, FullName, CreationTime, Extension | Where-Object {$_.Extension -like $ext} | export-csv C:\Files.csv -NoTypeInformation -append
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I wonder whether there is also a way to include both "for" loops so that I can loop through both .txt files?

Answer (score 1):

I just cleaned up your code.

Without knowing the content of Location.txt,
if there are repetitions in the drives, wouldn't `Output` contain dublettes of the files with different country?

Without your environment untested.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\05\SO_51183354.ps1
$fileHeaders = @('country','cDrive','dDrive')
$Extensions = (Get-Content 'C:\temp\Extension.txt') -replace '\*' -split ','

$LocContent = Import-Csv "C:\temp\Location.txt" -Header $fileHeaders |
    Where-Object {($_.country -ne $null) -and 
                  ($_.cDrive  -ne $null) -and 
                  ($_.dDrive  -ne $null) }

$NumberOfDays = Read-Host 'Max file age in days?'
$SizeOfFile   = Read-Host 'Min file size (in kb or mb)?'
$FileAge = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$NumberOfDays)

$Output = ForEach($Row in $LocContent){
  Get-ChildItem $Row.cDrive,$Row.dDrive -Force -Recurse |
    Where-Object {($_.Extension -in $Extensions)  -and
                  ($_.LastWriteTime -gt $FileAge) -and
                  ($_.Length -gt $SizeOfFile) } | 
      Select-Object -Property `
          @{N='File Basename' ;E={$_.BaseName}}, 
          @{N='File Extension';E={$_.Extension}},
          @{N='size in MB'    ;E={$_.Length/1MB}},
               Directory,
               CreationTime, 
               LastWriteTime, 
          @{N="Location"      ;E={$Row.country}}         
}

$Output | Format-Table -Auto
$Output | Out-Gridview
$Output | Export-Csv '\NewData.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```