# How to get the AD full name of the net user of the file you scan in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Currently my code to scan the full name of the net user is like the following but it only outputs the full name of the device that is used to scan the files instead of the full name of the person who creates the file. Anyone helps? Thanks!

```
 $Output = ForEach($Row in $LocContent){ 
          Get-ChildItem $Row.drivePath -Force -Recurse |
              Where-Object LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$NumberOfDays) |
                    Where-Object {($_.Extension -in $Extensions)} | 
                        Where-Object {$_.length/$SizeOfFile -gt 1} | 
                          Select-Object -Property @{N='File Basename';E={$_.BaseName}}, 
                              @{N='File Extension';E={$_.Extension}},
                              @{N='size(MB)';E={[Math]::Round(($_.Length/1024kb),2)}},
                              Directory, 
                              @{Name='Full Name of Net User';Expression={([adsi]"WinNT://$env:userdomain/$env:username,user").fullname}},
                              CreationTime, 
                              LastWriteTime, 
                              @{N='Last Created Within (Number of Days)';E={$NumberOfDays}},
                              @{N="Location";E={$Row.country}}       
}
```

Comment: Already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678847/how-to-extract-metadata-using-a-specific-filename-get-childitem-rather-than-lo

Comment: So some ideas of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51189503/6811411) to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183354/how-to-output-multiple-file-extensions-stored-in-a-txt-file-on-powershell) were helpful. I suggest you take the [tour] and read: [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and [why vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).